# Replacing a value in Pandas takes an excessive amount of time

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, performance

I have this function, and it runs in milliseconds if I remove the line     `df.loc[df['ln_1_adr'] == df['ln_2_adr'], df['ln_1_adr']] = ''`

The line is meant to eliminate redundant address information from line 1. I'm not sure what could be taking it so long. The chunk size being passed to the function is a 3000x8 dataframe.

```
def concatenate_fields(df):
    df = pd.DataFrame(df).copy()
    for col in ['ln_1_adr','ln_2_adr','city_adr', 'state_adr', 'zip_5_adr','zip_4_adr']:
        df[col] = df[col].str.strip()
        if col in ('ln_1_adr','ln_2_adr'):
            df[col] = df[col].str.replace(r"-", " ", regex=False)
    df.loc[df['ln_1_adr'] == df['ln_2_adr'], df['ln_1_adr']] = '' #This line takes forever
    df["zip_plus_4"] = df.zip_5_adr.str.cat(df['zip_4_adr'], sep=' ', na_rep='')
    df["ADDRESS"] = df.ln_1_adr.str.cat(df[['ln_2_adr','city_adr', 'state_adr', 'zip_plus_4']], sep = ' ', na_rep='').str.strip()
                                            
    return df
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some weird structure in the problematic line. I re-wrote the line and it should be fast now.

```
# replace address line one with empty string if it equals address line two
df['ln_1_adr'].loc[df['ln_1_adr'] == df['ln_2_adr']] = ''
```